# Can you end Heat Metal's disadvantage by dropping an affected weapon on your turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Heavily related to [my previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152465)  (possibly a duplicate in a way)
[*heat metal*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/heat-metal) states:

> If a creature is holding or wearing the object and takes the damage from it, the creature must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or drop the object if it can. **If it doesn't drop the object**, it has disadvantage on attack rolls and ability checks until the start of your next turn...

If you are suffering disadvantage from holding a weapon affected by heat metal, does dropping the weapon remove the disadvantage or does the phrase "If it doesn't drop the object" only refer to the possibility of dropping it at the time of the casting?

Answer (score 2):

It refers to dropping it anytime the damage occurs *and* the Constitution saving throw is failed (emphasis added):

> Choose a manufactured metal object, such as a metal weapon or a suit of heavy or medium metal armor, that you can see within range. You cause the object to glow red-hot. **Any creature in physical contact with the object takes 2d8 fire damage when you cast the spell**. Until the spell ends, you can use a bonus action on each of your subsequent turns **to cause this damage again**.
>
> If a creature is holding or wearing the object and **takes the damage from it, the creature must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or drop the object if it can**. If it doesn't drop the object, it has disadvantage on attack rolls and ability checks until the start of your next turn.

As I understand it, if the Constitution save is failed, the creature *must* drop the object if possible. If the object cannot be dropped, then disadvantage comes into play. If the save is passed, the creature does not have to drop the object and does not suffer disadvantage.

Comment: For clarification, you believe that if a target succeeds on the saving throw they do not suffer disadvantage? Even though it says that if you don't drop it you have disadvantage?

Comment: I believe so. I think the Constitution save determines whether the creature is required to drop it and the disadvantage is a consequence of not being able to fulfill that requirement, rather than a consequence of not dropping it period. Granted this is all RAI, not RAW, but I see the saving throw as a creature steeling itself against the heated metal. Essentially, if it's strong enough to not drop the object to begin with, it should be able to use it without issue...

Comment: @Medix2 I hadn't considered it before, but it actually is a valid reading to interpret the last sentence as a continuation of the consequences for failing the saving throw. Of course it's also equally valid to read it as an independent sentence that applies regardless of the result of the saving throw. It's unfortunately ambiguous.

Comment: @RyanThompson That would make a good answer to my other question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152465) if you're interested

Comment: ...But now that I say that, I'm not 100% sure. I can see the interpretation going either way. It could be interpreted narratively that the creature is strong enough to not drop it, but it's still so hot they have trouble using it.

Comment: So if the object could not be dropped by the creature, who failed their saving throw. And then on their own turn, they dropped it, what would you say happen to the disadvantage (is it removed or does it remain)?

Comment: Would you be alright with me closing this question and opening up a new single question more generally about *heat metal*?

Comment: That situation is ambiguous as written also and would be up to interpretation too. Thinking narratively again, I can see it argued that since the creature is relieved of the item, it no longer causes them an issue so no disadvantage. But it could also be viewed that the pain caused still lingers for the turn, so there would be disadvantage.

Comment: Yeah, I think that'd be fine. The big issue with the spell comes from how ambiguous it is, so I think it'll boil down to the DM.

Comment: I answered your new question and shifted this answer over there if the question ends up being deleted. I'll keep an eye on the notifications and make edits if needed.